# Sharp Architecture - Entry Point was not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharp-architecture

1. Install a fresh Sharp Architecture application
2. Run **YourApp.Web.Mvc**
3. See the following error:

> Entry Point was not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue:**

The **MVC4** DLL is being referenced by default rather than **MVC3**

**Solution:**

1. Remove `System.Web.Mvc` reference from **MyApp.Web.Mvc**
2. Add reference to `System.Web.Mvc` runtime version **3.0.0**

Answer (score 1):

Or better yet upgrade it to MVC4.
Step by step instructions here http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/upgrading-sarp-to-mvc4/